# Some questions about using h-parameters to model a BJT

Tags: bjt

Below is an excerpt from a book which explains why h-parameters model is suitable for a BJT:

[image]

I have couple of questions regarding the paragraph and use of h-parameters:

**1-)** The text says the reason h-parameters used is that it fits BJT CE as a model. But if we use h-parameters for BJT the independent variables become the base current I1=Ib and the collector voltage V2=Vce. But BJT is a voltage controlled current source which means Vbe must be the independent variable. Why not using a model where V1=Vbe is independent instead of I1=Ib?

**2-)** Why are h-parameters are valid only for small-signal analysis but not large signal-analysis? Is that because they are not constant for large signals? Why?

Comment: The BJT is a non-linear device so, only for a very small signal we can use small-signal approximation and treat the BJT as a linear device. http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee105/sp08/discussions/discussion3.pdf and this http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/412/handouts/5.6%20Small%20Signal%20Operation%20and%20Models/section%205_6%20%20Small%20Signal%20Operation%20and%20Models%20lecture.pdf

Answer (score 2):

> But BJT is a voltage controlled current source which means Vbe must be the independent variable.

1. This is *your* bias (input voltage). Many users put emphasis on input current rather than voltage. Even so, current gain for many BJT is not constant over the whole universe of operating current. As for output, a current source is an obvious choice.
    Nothing stops you from characterizing BJT with H-parameters for common-base or common-collector.
2. H-parameters only apply to **linear circuits**. Can't use them when output is not proportional to input. For example, a sine wave going in should yield a sine wave coming out of the 2-port.

Comment: So the bottom-line for BJT CE is: V1=f1(I1, V2) and I2=f2(I1, V2) where V1=Vbe and I2=Ic are dependent variables; and I1=Ib and V2=Vce are independent variables?

Comment: @newage2000 v1/i1  is usually strongly dependent on \$h_{11} \$, because \$ h_{12} \$ is often insignificant (except at radio frequencies). Similarly, i2 is strongly dependent on i1 via the \$ h_{21} \$ parameter, because \$ h_{22} \$ is often swamped by a bias or load resistor at the output.  Perhaps it is a brain-stretch to consider all the elements of a 2-port, but it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the relevant 4-pole equations, which are the basis for the definition of the h-parameters:

V1=h11*I1+h12*V2  and 
I2=h21*I1+h22*V2.

Now you can see the advantage of using the h-parameters:

1) It is very easy to measure the most relevant parameters h11 and h21 because, in this case, we require V2=0 (second part in both equations disappears). This condition V2=0 is very easy to realize because V2 is a small signal ac term - and a simple large capacitor is sufficient across the output of the BJT.

2.) Becaus both parameters h12 and h22 can be neglected in many cases, we can replace both parameters h11 and h12 with the corresponding physical parameters rbe and beta, respectively.

3.) Note that the definition of the h-parameter set has NOTHING to do with the physical behaviour of the BJT (voltage controlled current source). The only reason for using these parametrs is the fact that they can easily be measured.

For example: For measuring h11 we make V2=0 and the remaining part V1=h11*I1 can easily be used to find I1 as a function of V1 (as you can see, now I1 is the dependent variable).

4.) Further comment: The first part in the first equatiuon as well as the second part in the second equation fulfills Ohms law. That is the reason that both equations are valid under LINEAR conditions only. Because the BJT is a strongly non-linear device both equations apply to very small signals only - and are dependent on the corresponding DC bias point.

Comment: I should add that all h-parameters are valid for low frequencies only (app. some 10th of kHz) - as long as the voltage-current relationships can be considered as REAL (without any remarkable phase shift)

Answer (score 2):

Hybrid parameters are one of many *linear* ways to model a two-port electrical network, be it linear or non-linear. In other words, the model is linear *by definition*.

As your textbook explains, you have 4 quantities: \$I_1, V_1, I_2, V_2\$. You can choose two as independent variables and consequently the other two becomes dependent.

If you choose \$I_1\$ and \$V_2\$ as independent variables you get what is called the *h-parameter model* and, since the model is linear, the dependent variables are obtained through a linear combination. For a BJT CE configuration we identify those general quantities with \$i_b, v_{be}, i_c, v_{ce} \$, hence the model's linear equations are:

$$
i_c = h_{fe} i_b + h_{oe} v_{ce} \\
v_{be} = h_{ie} i_b + h_{re} v_{ce} \\
$$

Note that I used lowercase letters to identify the 4 quantities, because they represent only the small-signal components of the actual quantities. That's because in reality the actual circuital quantities \$I_b, V_{be}, I_c, V_{ce} \$ are related by non-linear equations. In particular we could write them, in a generic way, as:

$$
I_C = I_C(I_B,V_{CE}) \\
V_{BE} = V_{BE}(I_B,V_{CE}) \\
$$

These functions are usually obtained, for a specific device, by measurement and displayed on its datasheet. For example, the plot of \$I_C\$ versus \$V_{CE}\$ having \$I_B\$ as parameter, is the family of curves known as *collector characteristics* of a BJT.

Relating these non-linear equations to the linear model requires application of the [multivariable Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor%27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions).

The 1st order expansion around the point \$Q = (I_{BQ},V_{CEQ})\$ (called the quiescent point) turns out to be:

$$
I_C \approx I_C(I_{BQ},V_{CEQ}) 
 + \frac {\partial I_C} {\partial I_B} \Delta I_B
 + \frac {\partial I_C} {\partial V_{CE}} \Delta V_{CE} \\[2em]
V_{BE} \approx V_{BE}(I_{BQ},V_{CEQ}) 
 + \frac {\partial V_{BE}} {\partial I_B} \Delta I_B
 + \frac {\partial V_{BE}} {\partial V_{CE}} \Delta V_{CE}
$$

Those partial derivatives are calculated at the quiescent point and they are identified with the h-parameters *at that quiescent point*. In particular:

$$
h_{fe} = \frac {\partial I_C} {\partial I_B} @ Q  \\[2em]
h_{oe} = \frac {\partial I_C} {\partial V_{CE}} @ Q \\[2em]
h_{ie} = \frac {\partial V_{BE}} {\partial I_B} @ Q  \\[2em]
h_{re} = \frac {\partial V_{BE}} {\partial V_{CE}} @ Q 
$$

After all this math, let's answer your two points more directly:

1) You could use almost any parameter system to model a two-port device around a quiescent point. The h-parameter model turns out to be convenient since the parameters can be easily measured at low frequencies.

2) The validity of h parameters for small signals only depends on the fact that they are obtained by a Taylor approximation (linearization), which is valid only as long as you don't stray away from the chosen quiescent point too much.